# Nested inline operator <% giving a new line error

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code line in my aspx

```
<ItemTemplate>                
    <a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/BusinessHandlers/FileDownLoad.ashx?FileName=<%#Eval("FileName") %>") %>">My text</a> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

Now when I load the page I am getting 
Compiler Error Message: CS1010: Newline in constant

The code allowed me to compile at first and I was able to run. The page shows the above exception.
If I replace `<%# Eval("FileName") %>` with a static value there it works fine.  Any guess why this happens? Is there something around nesting `<%` operator? Any help is greatly appreciated.
I have to have that Eval part there so that I get the value from server.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I suppose you are inside of a `GridView` or a `Repeater` control and you want to correctly evaluate the Url to a file. You should not include another `<%%>` when already inside of these operators. And also replace `=` to `#` in order to correctly bind the data to anchor element. Code below should work for you!

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <a href="<%# Page.ResolveUrl(string.Format("~/BusinessHandlers/FileDownLoad.ashx?FileName={0}", Eval("FileName"))) %>">My text</a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Its not working though. Getting an error invalide expression term ")". There is a "$" after Page.ResolveUrl( . Is it needed? That gave me an error too. Yes its in a grid.

Comment: It is because you are not using C# 6 or above. Updated the answer.

Comment: Happy to help! :)